# QPushButton : disconnecting the clicked signal

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using QPushButton called `add_routes_pb`. I am connecting its `clicked` signal to a slot function i.e `Add_routes_func` which is in another class.

**Problem Faced**: The problem which I am facing is, if I press the `add_routes_pb` for the first time, then the function is run only once. But If I am pressing the button for the second time, the function is run 2times, and so on.

I guess the problem is because I am not disconnecting the push-buttons clicked signal. I tried to do that but still the function is run multiple times depending on the number of click.

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self):
         self.num = 9999
         self.flag = 0
         self.b = B()
    
    def func1(self)
         if self.flag == 1:
              self.b.add_routes_pb.clicked.disconnect(lambda: self.Add_routes_func(self.num))
             
         self.flag = self.b.add_routes_pb.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Add_routes_func(self.num))
    def run(self):
         self.dlg.add_new_routes_pb.clicked.connect(self.func1)



Class B():
    def __init__(self):
         pass
    def Add_routes_func(self, num):
        print(num)
        flag = 1
        return flag
```

Here, I am trying to track a flag, `if flag == 1`, then I am disconnecting the signal to the pushbutton. But still I am facing the error, the function is getting called multiple time If pushbutton is clicked. Am I disconnecting it wrong?

Comment: Where do you use `self.flag = 1`?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that `Class B` also has a `QPushButton`. From the code in your question, it appears that is the fact.

`connect` function returns a `Connection` object. Therefore, you need to use `self.flag = 1` after connection. Also, you missed `b` in `self.Add_routes_func`. Because `Class A` doesn't have a function named `Add_routes_func`. So use this:

```
def func1(self)
    if self.flag == 1:
        self.b.add_routes_pb.clicked.disconnect(lambda: self.b.Add_routes_func(self.num))
         
    self.b.add_routes_pb.clicked.connect(lambda: self.b.Add_routes_func(self.num))
    self.flag = 1
```

Comment: I don't know if the answer will work or not. Because your script is not so clear to me.